# How do I instantiate an empty workbook using Excel Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, if-statement, excel-interop

I have this code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
var excelApp = new Excel.Application();

if (CurrentWorkbook.Version == "Release")
{
}
else
{
      if (File.GetLastWriteTime(CurrentWorkbook.DataPath + CurrentWorkbook.FileName + ".xlsm").Date != DateTime.Today)
      {
           var MRPData = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"H:\@Business_Reporting_Today\MRP\Blank MRP Workbook.xlsm", 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
      }
}
```

and then later in my project I have:

```
if (CurrentWorkbook.Version == "Release")
{
}
else
{
    excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

    MRPData.Close(0);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(MRPData);
    excelApp.Quit();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
}
```

However since I declared MRPData in an if code block, it of course, "Does not exist in current context," in the later code block.  I have tried to pull the declaring of the variable out of the code block with this:

```
var MRPData = new Excel.Workbook();
```

This gets rid of the compile errors but gives me a run time error that says,

> 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).'

How do I fix this problem, so that I can declare it outside of the if code block?

Comment: You've got a COM registration conflict. Basically you are either referencing a different version of Interop.Excel (14 or 15) in your project compared to that which has been installed on your machine! check which version you have installed..office14 / 15.. perhaps both!

Comment: @Wheels73, I have office 14 but not 15.  How do I fix this issue?  If I leave it the old way in the code block then I have no issues but I need to do something now that I need to pull it out of the code block.

Comment: Changing the position of the code that instantiates the Workbook wont give you a COM exception. You must be doing something slightly different. Perhaps the call to new Excel.Workbook does something different to the Open you call later on. Perhaps try not instancing the MRPData to a new workbook.. just declare it.. "Excel.Workbook MRPData; "

Comment: that gave me a compile error that says, "Use of unassigned local variable 'MRPData'"

Comment: Don't you then have MRPData = excelApp.Workbooks.Open?

Comment: `var MRPData = excelApp.Workbooks.Add` if you want to create new Workbook. Excel internal objects cannot be created directly via `new`.